# AngularJS testing rootScope.$broadcast not working

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

My controller method looks like this:

```
 angular.module(_appName_)

.controller('myController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('myObj', false);
    ......some code here.......
});
```

Jasmine test for testing call made to $rootScope.$broadcast looks like this:

```
describe("myController",function(){
    var scope,rootScope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        rootScope = $rootScope;           
    }));

    describe('myController', function() {
        it('rootScope broadcast called for myObj with false value', inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {

            var requestObj = '{"key":"1234567890"}';
            rootScope.requestObject = requestObj;

            $controller('myController', {
                $scope: scope,
                $rootScope: rootScope
            });


            spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();

            expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();

        }));
    });
});
```

It always gives me the following error:

Expected spy $broadcast to have been called.
        at Object.

When i try to put a breakpoint on the line where there is a call to broadcast in the controller method, it does hit the breakpoint while debugging. So the actual call is being made but the test doesn't recognize it somehow.

Can someone please let me know what am I missing here ?

Comment: What if you remove the inner describe and put the it directly after the beforeEach in the outer describe?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to include your module in `beforeEach` function.

And then make sure you mock your `spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast')` before you initialize your controller

```
$controller('myController', {
                $scope: scope,
                $rootScope: rootScope
            });
```

Here is a [plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZCBwdQFvmJ8eJjcKs21?p=preview) :)